# Data Extract Activity could not start issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, automation, data-extract

I migrated automations from one Business Unit to another (newly created) using Package Manager. Some of these automations have Data Extract activity. The Extract type is 'Data Extension Extract'. All these automations with the Data Extract activities are failing. When I tried creating new Data extract activities, those are failing as well. I don't receive any logs but this- ERROR:  Error has occurred.
And when I try to run the data extract activity from 'Activities' tab, I get below error-
[image]

Can there be a configuration issue in the backend that needs to be sorted given it is a new BU? Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: As you said even the new/manually created DataExtensionExtract is NOT working, I suggest to raise a Support ticket with SF Support

Answer (score 0):

Have you migrated your Data Extensions as well? Are they in the Shared Folder?
As to my knowledge (and test just now :)), you can't extract a DE in another BU without it being shared to that new BU.